# HttpPostedFile always null after deployment?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Please take a look at this short article..  [ARTICLE](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Uploading-Multiple-Files-using-JavaScript-Dynamic-FileUpload-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (count == 0)
            {
                claimno = PostData(hidnname, hidnlineitems); //this always gets executed
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)//does not gets executed after deployment
            {
                 // code to save files in database
            }
}
```

I have tried to implement this my project and it works just fine as long as I run the application on local machine using visual studio. After deployment it seems that `for loop` never gets executed. My guess is that `Request.Files` is null. But it works fine when i run the project on local machine. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: If `Request.Files` was null you'd get `NullReferenceException`. Can you add some output of `Request.Files` right before the `for` loop and see the `Count` property?

Comment: @Ani It's zero. Even though I added a file.